# Angular/Prime NG Input binding to an OBJECT displays [object object], how to display a field of the object in the UI?

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm binding an object to an angular input like:

```
 <input formControlName="tenantLegalNameId"  type="text" pInputText [required]="true" [style]="{'width':'100%'}" />
```

the form control is set like this:

```
testform = new FormGroup({
various form controls with no issues...
 tenantLegalNameId: new FormControl({ value: "", disabled: true }, [
        Validators.required,
      ]),
more form controls set here that work fine...
})
```

then the tenantLegalNameId form control is bound like this:

```
this.stationInfoForm.patchValue({
      tenantLegalNameId: {
        tenantId: this.stationInfo?.tenantLegalNameId,
        tenantLegalName: this.stationInfo?.tenantLegalName,
      },
      //tenantLegalNameId: this.stationInfo?.tenantLegalName,
      stateId: this.stationInfo?.stateId,
      typeOfEntity: this.stationInfo?.typeOfEntity,
      stationCallLetters: this.stationInfo?.stationCallLetters,
      stationFrequency: this.stationInfo?.stationFrequency,
    });
```

The input displays [Object Object]. How can I display just "tenantLegalNameId?.tenantLegalName" in the input in the UI?

I've tried:

```
<form [formGroup]="testform">
various inputs that work here...
<input formControlName="tenantLegalNameId?.tenantLegalName"  type="text" pInputText [required]="true" [style]="{'width':'100%'}" />
more inputs that work here...
</form>
```

also:

```
<input formControlName="tenantLegalNameId" [value]="testform.get('tenantLegalNameId').tenantLegalName"  type="text" pInputText [required]="true" [style]="{'width':'100%'}" />
```

But neither of those work.

EDIT- I found a solution that works.
I just randomly came across this stackblitz as I was searching for a solution :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kdb3qx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

I changed the value set on the form control to a function like:

```
this.stationInfoForm = new FormGroup({
  // tenantLegalNameId: new FormControl({ value: "", disabled: true }, [
  //   Validators.required,
  // ]),
  tenantLegalNameId: this.getGroup(),
```

and getGroup looks like:

```
getGroup() {
return this.formBuilder.group({
  tenantId: this.stationInfo?.tenantLegalNameId,
  tenantLegalName: this.stationInfo?.tenantLegalName,
  relationshipName: ''
})
```

}

and the secret sauce that makes it happen in the UI, wrap the input with a div and set a "formGroupName" attribute to the original object value (tenantLegalNameId), then set the Input's "formControlName" to the field I want from the object, like so:

```
 <div class="col-6" formGroupName="tenantLegalNameId">
  <label for="tenantLegalNameId">Tenant Legal Name *</label>
  <input formControlName="tenantLegalName" type="text" pInputText [required]="true" [style]="{'width':'100%'}" />
  <small class="p-error" *ngIf="tenantLegalNameId.isTouched && tenantLegalNameId.invalid" [hidden]="true">Required Field</small>
</div>
```

Don't know who to give credit to for this, but thanks.

Comment: the formControlName maps to the property on the FromGroup. Typically you would create a new FormControl as `FormControl(<value here>, [<Validators Here>])`. In your code, you've set the value of the FormControl to an object instead of an actual value

Comment: Understood. 
This is a client's project, so this is inherited code. 
It works fine in Material, but we're converting the entire site from Material to Prime NG and the pInputText type seems to work a little differently.

I did find a solution that works.

Comment: The initialization is OK, you can set the value and disabled it at the same time. But, the type of the field is `string`, yet later on you try to set it with a value of `{ tenantId?: string, tenantLegalName?: string }`. At this point, it will break because the object `toString()` method will return the aforementioned `[Object Object]`

Comment: See edit above for solution.